# Chat Posts and escaped asterisks

Tags: bug, chat, markdown-rendering

The issue in itself is simple:

```
\***Foo***
```

will get rendered as

> ***Foo***

not very visible here, but prominent in chat: the finishing asterisk is also bolded

Comment: `**\*Foo***` works if all you care about is symmetry.  It bolds both asterisks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiously, in a question / answer it becomes

> ***Foo***

which is *not* what I expected at all!  In comments it does give ***Foo*** as expected.

(Ps. I know this isn't an answer, but I couldn't exactly demonstrate this in a comment, could I?)

Comment: Here's what it looks like in a comment: \***Foo***

Comment: seems the markup processor for questions and answers is a different implementation for chat and comments

Comment: Basically, Markdown is a thousand ambiguities flying in close formation. (Apologies to Peter da Silva.)